# Why is the Weblogic server not releasing memory?

Tags: weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

In my organization, we conduct Data Entry Operation though a 3-tier Application System. The Configuration is shown as below:

- Operating System :  Linux
- Application Software has been built using: JSF (a Java EE Framework Technology)
- Database : Oracle 11g

The Problem: For each entry an Enterprise bean is created and kept in a queue inside the Weblogic Sever. The Bean is being sent to the database but the memory used for the bean is not being released. As a result for a certain time duration, when the hits reach a peak and the memory is being used up to say 16GB or more, the server hangs responding and it has to be restarted in order to release the memory.

To be on the safe side, we have set the maximum simultaneous connections to the maximum. But this doesn't help.

What may be the problem and how to tune the system?

Answer (score 1):

> The Bean is being sent to the Database but the memory used for the
>   bean is not being released.

Likely memory leak here because of certain resources such as DB connection not being closed in the code.

Take a [Heap Dump into an HPROF file](http://visualvm.java.net/heapdump.html) and run this using Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool or [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)
or monitor this using [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html)